# Proving a matrix has no real eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How does one go about proving that a matrix has no real eigenvectors or values? This would be for a general case, and all that is known is the nxn matrix A is invertible, and that A^2=-I

I tried using determinants and the characteristic polynomial, but as it is a general case with no specific matrix I can not figure out how to actually prove this. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose $X$ is an eigenvector with real eigenvalue $\lambda$.  What can you say about $A^2X$?

Comment: If $A$ had a real eigenvalue $\lambda$, then, for some nonzero column $x$ you would have $Ax=\lambda x$. But then $A^2x=\lambda^2x$ and $-Ix=-x$, thus (because $x\ne 0$) we would have $\lambda^2=-1$...

Comment: If $A$ satisfies $x^2 + 1 = 0$ then it’s minimal polynomial is one of $(x-i)$, $(x+i)$, or $(x^2 + 1)$. Consequently the only possible eigenvalues of the characteristic polynomial are $\pm i$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that $\ A\ $ be a *real* matrix for your question to have a satisfactory answer.  [Stinking Bishop's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/700480/stinking-bishop) comment shows that the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $ can only be $\ \lambda=\pm i\ $, so if $\ A\ $ is real, and $\ Ax=\lambda x\ $ with $\ x\ne0\ $, then $\ x\ $ cannot be real, because the expression on the left of the equation would have to be real, but the one on its right would have to have at least one non-zero imaginary entry.

If $\ A\ $ is not required to be real, however, it *can* have real eigenvectors. If
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}\ , 
$$
for example, then $\ A^2=-I\ $, and $\ A\ $ has eigenvectors $\ \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\ $, corresponding to the eigevalue $\ \lambda=i\ $, and $\ \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\ $, corresponding to the eigevalue $\ \lambda=-i\ $.